# Increase point size of point cloud in PCL for visualization

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I am visualizing two point clouds inside PCL Visualizer. Below is the code snippet:

```
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/visualization/pcl_visualizer.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer viewer("Cloud Viewer");

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>::Ptr face (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGBA>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("face.pcd", *face);

    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr nose (new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::io::loadPCDFile ("nose.pcd", *nose);

    viewer.addPointCloud(face,"face");
    viewer.addPointCloud(nose, "nose");
    
    viewer.spin();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to increase the point size of the `nose` point cloud. Please note that pressing `+` key increases the point size for the complete window.

Comment: Hi, are you sure that you spent enough time searching the web ? `PCL point size in viewer` returns [the answer](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php) as first result with Google and DuckDuckGo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [pcl visualizer example](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcl_visualizer.php) <-- [updated-link](https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/pcl_visualizer.html#pcl-visualizer):

```
viewer.setPointCloudRenderingProperties(pcl::visualization::PCL_VISUALIZER_POINT_SIZE, 1, "cloud name");
```

With 1 being the size of the points.

Comment: I don't know why but I wasn't able to get this simple API. I was looking at `vtk` and trying to modify the point cloud from `vtk`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The above seems to have no effect whatsoever on the actual size of visualized points

Comment: PCLVisualizer example updated link --> https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/pcl_visualizer.html#pcl-visualizer